# Dartboard paradox and understanding independence

Tags: probability, terminology, definition

1. - By definition, events $A$ and $B$ are **independent** if $$P(A \cap
         B) = P(A)\:P(B).$$ Thus if an event $A$ happens almost never
     $\left(P(A)=0\right),$ then
     $A$ is independent of all events, including itself. So, hitting the
     exact centre of a dartboard (happens almost never) and hitting within its inner ring are independent events.
   - On the other hand, it is standard to characterise
     independence as follows:

     > Two events are **independent** if the occurrence of one does not
     > affect the probability of occurrence of the other.

     Since hitting the exact centre of a dartboard guarantees hitting
     within its inner ring (which is otherwise not guaranteed), the
     two events are dependent.

   Isn't this a contradiction?? If yes, then do we accept that the definition of independence is not meant to fully correspond to its verbal/intuitive characterisation?
2. Is there any semantic difference between the following two versions?

   > $(i)$ Two events are independent if the occurrence of one does not
   > affect the probability of occurrence of the other.

   > $(ii)$ Two events are independent if the occurrence of one does not
   > affect the occurrence of the other.

---

### ADDENDUM

On further pondering, I have resolved both questions:

2.
Consider this experiment: flip two fair coins, letting $H_1$ be the event that the first coin lands on Heads, and $X$ be the event that the coins land on different sides. Then $$ P\left(H_1 \cap X\right)=\frac14=P(H_1)\:P(X);$$ i.e., $H_1$ and $X$ are independent events.

Knowledge that $H_1$ happens reduces the possible number of ways that $X$ can eventuate—from $2$ (outcomes HT and TH) to $1$ (outcome HT)—but does not change the *probability* $\left(\frac12\right)$ of $X.$

1.
The following revision characterises pairwise independence more clearly and accurately:

> Let $P(A)\neq0.$
>
> Events $A$ and $B$ are independent iff knowing that $A$ happens doesn't change $B$'s probability.

In this informal characterisation, almost-never events are now excluded from being conditioned on. (What does it even mean to say that an almost-never event has happened: in what sense have I hit the exact centre of a dartboard?) It motivates the definition of pairwise independence, which *does* allow both events to be impossible.

Comment: P.S. This post isn't a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3692185/formal-definition-of-independence-of-events) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043230/i-cant-grasp-how-these-events-are-independent) as my specific points/questions have not been addressed.

Comment: No idea on the first question - but its an interesting question. For the second, I suspect/feel the second statement is a simplified version of the first. The first is an accurate and essentially complete characterization of the mathematical definition of independence. The second is the type of thing I would say in a casual conversation or with someone for whom bringing in words like "probability" either bores or scares them.

Comment: Formal definition of independence comes from $P(A|B)=P(A)$ and  $P(B|A)=P(B)$ and only when $P(B)>0,P(A)>0$ it gives $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$. So conclusions for case $P(A)=1$, as I think, are clear. But what definition are you intend to use when $P(B)=P(A)=0$?

Comment: As zkutch mentions, the colloquial descriptions of independence are based on the "conditional probability equals unconditional probability" formulation, which breaks down when conditioning event has probability zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Events $A$ and $B$ are indeed defined to be independent if $P[AB] = P[A]P[B]$.  This definition holds for all cases, including cases when $P[A]=0$ and/or $P[B]=0$. The definition leads to your desired interpretation "knowing if $B$ occurred does not affect the likelihood of $A$"  in the special case $P[B]>0$, since it means $P[A|B] = P[A]$ in that case. It does not allow your interpretation in the case when $P[B]=0$, **since we cannot condition on a zero-probability event.  So indeed, there are peculiarities when $P[B]=0$ since intuition fails in that case.** Nevertheless, your intuition is still useful since it applies when $P[B]>0$.

It may also be helpful to observe that if $P[B]=0$ then $P[A|B^c] = P[A]$, which is intuitively what we would want when $A$ and $B^c$ are independent.

---

A situation about darts similar to the one you posed can be addressed by the definitions of **conditioning with respect to a random variable**. For a dartboard, we can imagine $(X,Y)$ uniformly distributed over a 2-d ball of radius 1.  Then define $R = \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ as the distance from the center.  Consider the events:
$$ A = \{R \leq 1/10\}, B = \{R = 1/10\}$$
Now $P[B]=0$ so $A$ and $B$ are independent.  Nevertheless this is similar to the situation you describe because $B \subseteq A$, so "intuitively" we would want $P[A|B]=1$. This holds if we use:
$$ P[A|R=r] = \frac{f_{R|A}(r)P[A]}{f_R(r)} $$
which shall be applied when $f_R$ and $f_{R|A}$ are continuous at point $r$ and $f_R(r)\neq 0$,
and we observe:
\begin{align}
f_R(r) &= \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 
2r  &  \mbox{ if $r \in [0,1]$}\\
0 & \mbox{else} 
\end{array}\right.\\
f_{R|A}(r) &= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{2r}{P[A]} & \mbox{ if $r \in [0,1/10]$} \\
0 & \mbox{ else} 
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
so
$$ P[A|R=r] = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \mbox{if $1/10 < r<1$} \\
1 & \mbox{ if $0<r\leq 1/10$} 
\end{array}\right.$$

Our expression $P[A|R=r]$ cannot be viewed as an instance of the definition of conditional probability $P[A|B]$ for events $A$ and $B$, since the event $\{R=r\}$ has probability 0.  Rather, it is an expression related to the definition of conditioning on a random variable $R$. Formally, you can say the random variable $Z$ defined by
$$ Z = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \mbox{if $R>1/10$} \\
1 & \mbox{ if $0\leq R \leq 1/10$} 
\end{array}\right.$$
is a "version" of the conditional expectation $E[1_A|R]$.  As such, it is almost surely the same as any other version. Thus, while this version takes the liberty to define $Z=1$ when $R=0$, and $Z=0$ when $R\geq 1$, this is fine because it only affects a set of measure 0.

Answer (score 1):

"On the other hand, it is standard to characterise pairwise independence as follows:

> Two events are independent if the occurrence of one does not affect the probability of occurrence of the other."

Errr no, I disagree; the usual *and informal* notion of independence is *slightly* different:

> Two events are said to be independent if knowledge that one of them has occurred does not cause you to assign a different value to the probability of the other.

That is, if $A$ and $B$ the two events in question and we know that $A$ had occurred, then we should use $P(B\mid A)$ are instead of $P(B)$ as the probability of $B$ in our calculations. Then, $A$ and $B$ are said to be independent events if $P(B\mid A)$ happens to be *equal* to $P(B)$. Thus, *informally*, $A$ and $B$ are said to be independent if $P(B\mid A) = P(B)$, or if one prefers, $P(A\mid B) = P(A)$. This is an *informal* definition because the conditional probabilities are not necessarily defined: the usual definition $\displaystyle P(B\mid A) = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$ assumes that $P(A) > 0$. It is much better to use the standard definition of (mutual) independence $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ which shows the symmetry of the relationship in contrast to $P(B\mid A) = P(B)$ which is asymmetric and if we stick in $P(A\mid B) = P(A)$ *also* to show symmetry, then we commit the sin of prolixity. Worse yet, *both* $A$ and $B$ might be events of probability $0$ making *both* $P(B\mid A)$ and $P(A\mid B)$ be undefined. In contrast, the definition of independence as $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$  has no such issues and is vastly to be preferred. $P(B\mid A) = P(B)$ is fine for informal use and for intuition, but not as a definition.  See also [this answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/24984/6633) over on stats.SE.